# jQuery add class to consecutive divs on click

Tags: jquery, onclick

Is it possible to add a class to consecutive divs when another element (Say a link) is clicked?

So for example, say I have this markup;

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="inner-div"></div> <!-- first div -->
    <div class="inner-div"></div> <!-- second div -->
    <div class="inner-div"></div> <!-- third div -->

    <a class="button clicker" href="#">Click me</a>

</div>
```

What I want to do is, when the `.clicker` link is clicked I want the first `.inner-div` to be given a class of `.show`. Then when `.clicker` is clicked again, the second `.inner-div` is given a class of `.show` (With each div keeping it's new class on every new click) and so on and so forth.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

On click of `.clicker` find the first `.inner-div` which doesn't have `.show` class, and add `.show`:

```
$(".clicker").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".inner-div:not(.show)").first().addClass("show");
});
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mzwgg8rs/

---

```js
$(function(){
   
    $(".clicker").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".inner-div:not(.show)").first().addClass("show");
});
    
});
```

```css
.inner-div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}

.inner-div.show
{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="inner-div"></div> <!-- first div -->
    <div class="inner-div"></div> <!-- second div -->
    <div class="inner-div"></div> <!-- third div -->

    <a class="button clicker" href="#">Click me</a>

</div>
```